# Gtk change multiple labels on button click

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gtk, gtk3

How can i change multible label values on single button click.Normally on a button click signal connect we can give only one user data.
Example code

```
void show_loop(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data)
{
    char buf[5];
    int no = TxBuf.plBuf[7];
  sprintf(buf, "%d",no);
  gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(user_data), buf);
}

ID_label=GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "label24"));
DLC_label=GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "label25"));

check = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "button3"));
g_signal_connect (check, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (show_loop), DLC_label);
```

I want to change both the labels on single button click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would define, allocate and fill a struct that contains all the widgets that may have to be changed dynamically in your initialization code:

```
typedef struct AppData {
    GtkWidget *id_label;
    GtkWidget *dlc_label;
} AppData;

...

AppData *app_data = g_new0 (AppData, 1);
app_data->id_label = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "label24"));
app_data->dlc_label = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "label25"));
```

The you use the `app_data` as userdata parameter and can access the widgets inside the signal handler as e.g. `app_data->id_label`.